# Add index in plist file programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, indexing, plist

I am creating a plist file programmatically direct to the documents directory. Here is my code..

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myList.plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"myList.plist"] ];
}
NSMutableArray *data ;
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

}
else
{
    // If the file doesn’t exist, create an empty dictionary
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
data = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
[data addObject:value1];
[data addObject:value2];
[data addObject:value3];
```

It creates plist file with this format..

```
<array>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>2</string>
        <string>3</string>
</array>
```

Now, I want to add another index to it like,

```
<array>
        <string>1</string>
        <string>2</string>
        <string>3</string>
</array>
<array>
        <string>11</string>
        <string>22</string>
        <string>33</string>
</array>
```

How can I add index programmatically in my plist file ?
Any help or suggestions will be appreciated !!

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to create an array of arrays in your plist? or just keep on adding indexes to your array?

Comment: Want to add array or arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myList.plist"];

NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
if (!data) {
    data = [NSMutableArray array];
}

[data addObject:@[value1,value2,value3]];

[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: You save me again..!! Works perfectly..!! many thanks again..!!

Comment: @iUser Glad to hear that, all the best.

Answer (score 1):

You should organize your plist as a dictionary. Corresponding to each keys you can store array objects. It is pretty easy. Store your arrays into a `NSDictionary` with proper keys as index number. Then sore that dictionary to the plist

```
<dict>
  <key>0</key>
  <array>
      <string>1</string>
      <string>2</string>
      <string>3</string>
  </array>
  <key>1</key>
  <array>
      <string>11</string>
      <string>22</string>
      <string>33</string>
  </array>
</dict>
```